# can anyone help me with unity error CS0201?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been working on a unity project, and I'm just starting out, I got this error for some code I had been working on and can't seem to figure it out. my code is below for the script with the error. I have read documents, watched videos, and done lots of other things too. the only thing I haven't done is ask a pro. By the way, I am using the Input actions asset so that I can connect with my Xbox controller. What I am trying to do is make this square move left and right. *blows you a kiss*

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class square : MonoBehaviour
{

    PlayerControls controls;

    Vector2 move;

    void Awake()
    {
        controls = new PlayerControls();

        controls.Gameplay.MovementRight.performed += ctx => MovementRight;

        controls.Gameplay.MovementLeft.performed += ctx => MovementLeft;
        
    }

    void MovementRight()
    {
        Vector2 move = new Vector2(1, 0);
    }

    void MovementLeft()
    {
        Vector2 move = new Vector2(1, 0);
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Gameplay.Enable();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.Gameplay.Disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? What line of code does it refer to?

Comment: Just adding that in addition to the line numbers you can generally double click an error in the Unity console to be taken directly to the relevant line.

Comment: Unity/Visual Studio/Code/Rider would have clearly stated _["Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"](https://www.google.com/search?q=CS0201&oq=CS0201&aqs=edge..69i57j0i512l2j0i30l4j0i5i30j69i60.1072j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)_ so I'm not sure why the focus on _"CS0201"_.   A quick Google would have taken you [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0201)

Answer (score 1):

Since your question was asked very decentrally. It is not possible to find the problem alone. I performed the necessary steps for you. Make sure you do the details correctly.

the `Action Type` must be value, because you need axis instead of one click button.

[image]

After setting the keys, save the settings as c # code and create your own character movement code. In the example below I named this code `InputManager`.

[image]

This will give you access to the motion axis from -1 to +1. By adding it to transform.position you have a simple motion algorithm.

```
public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerControlls _controller;
    void Start()
    {
        _controller = new PlayerControlls(); // instance a controller class for localize input
        
        _controller.Enable();  // controller must be enable at start
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var axis = _controller.Gameplay.Moving.ReadValue<float>(); // read value from player Input

        transform.position += new Vector3(axis, 0f); // moving algorithm
    }
}
```

Attach the code to your character and the movement will take place. Keep in mind that the new inputSystem has many different ways to control inputs, so learning them all takes more time.

Comment: thanks! I am very grateful for your help. Sorry I was so decentral!