# Unity2D - Player not moving no matter what I try

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I've been trying to get the new input system for Unity2D working, but I've been struggling; despite looking through multiple tutorials, even if I manage to get rid of all errors, I simply don't move.

Now, whenever I run the scene, I get flooded with this error over and over again:

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object PlayerM.Update () (at Assets/PlayerM.cs:27)`

Here's my player movement script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerM : MonoBehaviour
{

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Vector2 pos;
    public float speed = 2f;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void OnMove(InputValue value)
    {
        pos = value.Get<Vector2>();
        Debug.Log("Moving!");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + pos * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }    
}
```

And here's my input action asset:

[image: I've attempted switching between 2D and 1D axis to no avail.]

Comment: If you debugged this, you'll find `rb` is null. You never set this value. You probably need to add `rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();` in `start`

Comment: Today I answered a similar question. Use this guide: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/72157816/5740243](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72157816/5740243)

Comment: @KiynL Changing the code similar to how that answer put it did allow me to move, but I move so fast that the smallest tap of the arrow keys nearly sends me flying off.

Comment: You can use `Time.deltaTime` to adjust the speed but This code gives you access to use the new unity input system. Yourself by considering the axis. Set your proper motion algorithm.

Comment: Now one issue is that whenever I move around, it makes my y speed (set to rb.velocity.y) go into E numbers, so it never properly allows me to jump (also uses AddForce)

Answer (score 1):

To set the rigidbody to the attached component rather than null, try adding the line

```
rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
```

to your `Start()` method.